# laravel Form parameter

Tags: php, forms, laravel

i have this function in controller:

```
public function deleteItem( $id){
```

this in routes:

```
Route::delete('deleteItem', 'CommandsController@deleteItem')->name('deleteItem');
```

and i try to call it from view like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['deleteItem', $item->id]]) !!}
```

but when i confirm form i get in browser address:

> deleteItem?5

questions are how to get parameter in controller or how to pass parameter to get this address:

> deleteItem/5

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Route parameters in Laravel are being denoted via curly braces like

```
Route::delete('deleteItem/{id}', 'CommandsController@deleteItem')->name('deleteItem');
```

however according to the docs

```
echo Form::open(['action' => ['CommandsController@deleteItem', $item->id]])
```

is the correct way of sending parameters to the Controller in charge, which will send the $id parameter straight as the argument of the function.

Answer (score 0):

you don't pass the id parameter at all to the controller.

try changing

```
Route::delete('deleteItem'
```

to

```
Route::delete('deleteItem/:id'
```